# Jenkins integration with GitLab - port 22: Operation timed out

Tags: authentication, jenkins, ssh, gitlab

I was trying to create integration between Jenkins and GitLab using this tutorial: https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/how-to/create-ci-pipeline/
(without Step 3: Connect Your Project With The GitLab Repository)

So I have generated public and private keys, public was added in GitLab (Settings > SSH Keys) and private key file content was inserted into text area in Jenkins Project settings (Source Code Management > Credentials > SSH Username with private key > Private key)

[image]

After that following error appeared:

[image]

what can cause such strange issue? Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 0):

If you add public key to the profile of a specific GitLab user, you must:

1. Grant this user access to target project in GitLab.
2. Use username of that specific user (**instead of the `git` username**) when creating the SSH credentials in Jenkins.

Comment: I have given my user the Developer role in project scope and Maintainer role in group scope, put it into Username field but it is still not working (same error appears). Whether the reason may be: 1) using group name in repository URL? 2) OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY not RSA PRIVATE KEY?

Comment: > OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY not RSA PRIVATE KEY - I think this is the reason, you should use **RSA private key**.